# AudioOutputUnitStart replace the Music app

Tags: ios, audio, remoteio

My application (VoIP one) is using `kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord` category. Everything is working perfect expecting the fact that When calling `AudioOutputUnitStart` the Music App is replaced by my application.

Basically if I double tap the home button and flip to the music app, I can't see the default music app, instead I can see my application log near the music controls.

Anybody knows what can be?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you call this somewhere

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
[self becomeFirstResponder];
```

This may cause your app to appear in the music control bar